# NSInternalInconsistencyException when I call let app = XCUIApplication()

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-ui-testing

My boring code in my test:

```
override func setUp() {
        let app = XCUIApplication()
}
```

Gives me this error:

caught "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "No target application path specified via test configuration:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify in Xcode the target application of your UI Testing Target. For that go to the General settings for your UI Testing target and select a Target Application.

See below[image]

Comment: [Here are my settings](https://i.imgur.com/F0w5PZe.png). I have "Host" instead of "Target" as an option.

Comment: That look like a Unit Test Target but the code in your snippet is for UI Testing Target

Comment: How would I fix that?

Comment: Delete you target and recreate a new one that is a UI Testing Target (File > New > Target > UI Testing Target)